# record.getData is not a function

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, javascript-framework

I try to open window with sencha architect (extjs 4.2.0) and i have this error :

```
record.getData is not a function
```

My code (in my controller) is :

```
Ext.define('ModuleGestion.controller.MyController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    MajUtilisateurApplicatif: function(record) {
        var view = Ext.widget('FormUtilisateurApplicatif');      
        view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
    },

    init: function(application) {
        this.control({
            "gridpanel#GridUtilisateursApplicatifs": {
                itemdblclick: this.MajUtilisateurApplicatif
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Somebody can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to read the [documentation for itemdblclick](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.view.View-event-itemdblclick). You'll notice that the arguments passed, **in order**, for the event are:

- this (view)
- record
- item
- e
- eOpts

In essence, you're trying to load a form with a view for the record, which isn't correct.

I would suggest changing your method like so:

```
MajUtilisateurApplicatif: function( view, record, item, e, eOpts ) {
   var me = this,
       win = Ext.widget('FormUtilisateurApplicatif');      
   win.down('form').loadRecord(record);
}
```

A best practice is to always enumerate the arguments passed to the custom methods you create in your controller from event listeners. Not only will this help you avoid errors like the one above, but will also more helpfully communicate to other developers reading your code precisely what incoming arguments they have to deal with in your method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello,

I use this example :
http://peterkellner.net/2012/04/17/setting-values-in-a-form-using-the-sencha-architect-2-0-extjs-4-0/

I change abstractcomponent of the event binding "OnFormAfterRender" by component.

Thx!

Comment: Hmm, that example looks a bit convoluted to me. I'm not sure what the point in setting a custom property in the window is, just to reuse it to set the values in the form. Since the form already belongs to the window, it seems like a better approach (and less code, for that matter) to simply load the form with the record, like you were doing before. The only issue you had in your original example was that your function arguments were incorrect. Anyway, just my $0.02.